# How do I install the Fortran 9x compiler?

Tags: software-installation, fortran

I want to install a program called OSIRIS but, I need to get the Fortran 9x compiler. I was wondering how do I install it? I am using a Ubuntu 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GNU Fortran 95 compiler exists in the official Ubuntu repositories.

The package is called **gfortran**.

You can install it by command line in your terminal running

```
sudo apt install gfortran
```

See more info in the web gfortran package: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gfortran

Answer (score 2):

Install `gfortran`.

From `man gfortran`

```
   -std=std
       Specify the standard to which the program is expected to conform,
       which may be one of f95, f2003, f2008, gnu, or legacy.  The default
       value for std is gnu, which specifies a superset of the Fortran 95
       standard that includes all of the extensions supported by GNU
       Fortran, although warnings will be given for obsolete extensions
       not recommended for use in new code.  The legacy value is
       equivalent but without the warnings for obsolete extensions, and
       may be useful for old non-standard programs.  The f95, f2003 and
       f2008 values specify strict conformance to the Fortran 95, Fortran
       2003 and Fortran 2008 standards, respectively; errors are given for
       all extensions beyond the relevant language standard, and warnings
       are given for the Fortran 77 features that are permitted but
       obsolescent in later standards. -std=f2008ts allows the Fortran
       2008 standard including the additions of the Technical
       Specification (TS) 29113 on Further Interoperability of Fortran
       with C and TS 18508 on Additional Parallel Features in Fortran.
```